# I accidentally short the c wire and both units not turning back on

Tags: hvac, circuit-breaker, thermostat, nest

I was trying to installed my nest thermostats.the power were shut off but it seem some current still in, so it short the system
my question I can't located the fuse on the board so is that mean the fuse at the disconnected blow off.( I check both fuses by the look of it I can't tell)
any in put would be appreciated.
Thank you

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring diagram for your indoor unit (furnace or air handler) please?

Comment: is that part of an error code in the bottom picture?

Comment: these two units had the same problem which it showed no wire connected to each thermostat. and it seem it connect directed to thermostat from the HVAC is that possible I can't seem to located the furnace anyway in the house. they both indecent  from each other.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it seem there is no furnace anywhere in the house. Is that possible for the control board to connect direct to thermostat in the house btw these two are heat pump unit

Comment: @TarwinOnketpon -- that outdoor unit *needs* to be paired with an indoor unit of some flavor.  Where do all the ducts inside the house lead?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it seem going direct to thermostat one of this unit is for guest's bedroom so there is nothing there really. just gone into a wall.

Comment: @TarwinOnketpon -- have you checked the attic then?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sorry If I'm not explaining clear enough. the house have totally 4 unite of these heat pump. on four section of the house and I can't find any furnace inside the house at all not in the garage either so I assume the are none.  if there are where should I look for it? are all of this each require furnace ? and only two are not working which I'm sure it short while I'm installing a new thermostat.  I really appreciated

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel that is the only place I did not, is that possible for all of them will be in different places as well?

Comment: @TarwinOnketpon -- check the attic then, I bet you dollars to donuts its hiding up there

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'll have a look then. So you think they all should have different furnace right? since only two gone off. I hope it just a fuse on the furnace board

Comment: @TarwinOnketpon -- yeah, outdoor units of the style you have need their own indoor units

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thanks,I'll keep you posted.

Comment: can you find a low voltage fuse (like you would use in a car) on either of the boards?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes I used the 3 Amp fuse now.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ,Thank so much I found it and replace the fuse on one of it. the other one tuned out to be ok, but it not detected the W wire for some reason I cut the W wire and plug it in properly but still not detected. anyway the donuts dollars should be your. :p

Comment: @TarwinOnketpon -- if you could put together a writeup of where and how you found the problem and put it in the answer box, I'll +1 that for you :)

Answer (score 2):

after a few tips from @ThreePhaseEel I be able to fix the problem that I'm having.
after I short the circle on a furnace and blow off the fuse. Since I'm not a AC tech so I don't know much about a ac or a heat pump. beside the unit outside that they need a furnace unit inside as well. so the problem that I'm having with out knowing that so I'm not be able to located the furnace. since @ThreePhaseEel mentioned that the furnace should be under the attic so I went up there to found the furnace with a fuse blow off. so replace it with a new one. Tada! it works.
what I learned here that.
even you cut the power off on the AC to put on a new thermostat that the power the fed to a furnace might come from the different source. so make sure to cut the power off from the attic as well.
or I should protect the C wire at all cost so it won't touch any other cable and I should be good.
sorry about my bad english. this is the best I could do to answer to my own problem.
cheers.

Comment: Or simply never assume your wire is off. After shutting off power, assume you are wrong and get testers to confirm. I made the habit of testing the wire every time I work on something, so I'll never "forget" and it is simply part of my routine workflow.

Comment: Congrats on getting this figured out and thanks for coming back to post your answer! Make sure you click the check-mark next to your answer so others will know it's been resolved. Also, you're better at English than I am at your native language, so don't apologize.